# Run Quartz job synchronous

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a situation that I don't know how should I handle it.

I have a job in `quartz` which should start another nested job and get some results of the nested job and process them.

As I know, `quartz` run its job asynchronously. So, the thread which start the nested job cannot wait until the result of nested job being passed.

What is the solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all quartz has a thread pool for running its jobs.
You can read about it [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/index.html#page/Quartz_Scheduler_Documentation_Set/re-thr_threadpool_configuration.html):

In addition keep in mind that quartz can run jobs even in distributed manner. It allows to be run in cluster of 'active-active' servers, in this case you can't do any assumption on which of servers the job can be triggered. So implementing a singleton as jbh has stated can be tricky (at least you have been warned now :) )

In general, I think quartz should do what its good for - to run jobs.
I don't think that implementing any complicated logic on top of this is a good idea.
From your question I understand that you're trying to run one job from another (say job A runs job B). This makes sense if you have different trigger(s) assigned to A and B (otherwise why should B implemented as a quartz job?). So maybe you can refactor your code of job B so that the logic executed in B will be implemented in some class which is not related to quartz(say class C)? In this case you could assign different triggers to jobs A and B but inside just execute the code in class C?

Example (your approach):

```
class A implements Job {
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
      // do A's stuff
      // call Job B somehow (???)
  }
}


class B implements Job {
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
      // do something
  }
```

}

My suggestion:

```
class C {
   doSomeLogic(...) {...}
}


class A implements Job {
         public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws   JobExecutionException {
        // do A's stuff
        C c = new C();
        c.execute();  
  }


class B implements Job {
         public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {            
        C c = new C();
        c.execute();  
  }
```

}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I have thought about your solution but I wasn't sure It's the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Few ways. You can make some Static/Singleton type class that holds some sort of semaphore/session variables. Have the master job loop while checking this semaphore (synchronized for thread safety). And then retrieve the data similarly.

You can also utilize JobDataMap in a similar fashion. [JobDataMap example](https://vageeshhoskere.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/jobdatamap-in-quartz-scheduler/)